# Batch file to search through a folder and delete specific files

Tags: batch-file, search, delete-file

Firstly, this is the first batch file I've ever written and I really don't know the syntax.

This code should search and delete all the files, except that it doesn't actually delete them, they are still there. If someone could help me out, I would really appreciate it.

My script is as follows:

```
@echo off
color a 
echo.
For /R "E:\" %%G IN (*.onetoc2) do Echo del "%%G"
echo.
timeout 10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to remove the `Echo` before `del "%%G"`. The Echo is there to show you what will be deleted before you actually do it. Most of the people that answer questions here will add that in as a safeguard.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but is there a way to have it output what it is doing and still do it?

Comment: Yes. you use a program called `TEE` to do that. Lots of posts about it here.

Comment: No problem. In your case, you don't exactly need to use `TEE`. You can get away with `Echo del "%%G" & del "%%G"` just fine.

Answer (score 0):

remove the `Echo`.

Echo tells the computer to write things to the screen.

It's a good idea to do this for testing.

Once you are satisfied with the output and are sure, that it will do what you want, simply remove the `echo`

```
echo format c:
```

will not format your drive, but simply writes "format C:"
Remove the `echo` and you are in trouble. (well not really, because modern OS is too smart to do that)